# ExecCommand("ms-clearUndoStack") on Windows Vista

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control, windows-vista

I am using a WebBrowser control as a text editor in a Windows Forms application. For some reasons I need to clear the undo-stack of the browser after certain actions. To achieve this, I use

```
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("ms-clearUndoStack", false, null);
```

which works well on every OS but Windows Vista. On Vista I get the following ArgumentException:

```
   System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IHTMLDocument2.ExecCommand(String cmdID, Boolean showUI, Object value)
```

Is there a way to avoid the exception or maybe another way to clear the undo-stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command is not available on Windows Vista, as it is posted by msdn "[Commands A-C (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801227(v=vs.85).aspx#ClearUndoStack)" article

```
ms-clearUndoStack
Clears the undo history.
Minimum availability is IE11
```

[IE11 minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11) operating system requirements is Windows 7 SP1